# How to remove character "-" by sql queries?

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = REPLACE (post_title, "-", "");
```

It is giving message: `"0 rows affected"`

Please help me.

Comment: your query is working when i tested it on fiddle.

Comment: That means there is no record in database with -

Comment: No, I am sure that it has in title

Comment: which database server are you using?

Comment: It also don't work with "$" character

Comment: Not possible, the query is perfect. there might be some confusion regarding data....try like select * from wp_posts where post_title like('%-%')....there shouldnt be any data

Comment: check whether post_title have `-` value or not

Comment: Try using single quotes ' instead of double quotes ". Also check if you are in the right database. It is possible you have accidentally created the same table in the `master` database.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Unicode search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=-&preview=entity), there are at least 5 *"minus characters"*.

> - HYPHEN-MINUS U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS -
> - SUPERSCRIPT HYPHEN-MINUS U+207B SUPERSCRIPT MINUS ⁻
> - SUBSCRIPT HYPHEN-MINUS U+208B SUBSCRIPT MINUS ₋
> - SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS U+FE63 SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS ﹣
> - FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS U+FF0D FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS －

and [at least 4](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%24&preview=entity) *"dolar characters"*:

> - DOLLAR SIGN U+0024 DOLLAR SIGN $
> - SMALL DOLLAR SIGN U+FE69 SMALL DOLLAR SIGN ﹩
> - FULLWIDTH DOLLAR SIGN U+FF04 FULLWIDTH DOLLAR SIGN ＄
> - HEAVY DOLLAR SIGN U+1F4B2 HEAVY DOLLAR SIGN

Maybe you are replacing the wrong character, as Andrey suggested.

*Note: If some of the above characters do not render correctly on your browser, open this question's URL with a different one.*